# How create custom item in ListBox Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I need create own style of items in ListBox.Do I need create all custom ListBox or can just do custom Item?Any why I need example please
I'm using windows forms.Thank u!

Comment: I am not sure why people like to down vote certain questions. Asking is one great effort toward knowledge. But, that just my opinion anyway ;)

Comment: I want an answer too... Have you solved it?

Answer (score 2):

[Extending the ListBox to show more complex items](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15464/Extending-the-ListBox-to-show-more-complex-items)

this is a vb.net example:

[http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599375-ListBox-with-custom-items-(colors-images-text-alignment)](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?599375-ListBox-with-custom-items-%28colors-images-text-alignment%29)

Comment: Perfect. Just what I need!